# (Localstack) Queue peeking API prompt s3 404 error

Tags: amazon-s3, localstack

I am trying to use the sqs queue peeking api documented here (using both the path method and the query param method): https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/sqs/#peeking-into-queues

And the response is an s3 error (s3 was not enabled):

```
curl "http://localhost:4566/_aws/sqs/messages?QueueUrl=http://queue.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/queue"

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ErrorResponse><Error><Code>NoSuchBucket</Code><Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message><Type>Sender</Type></Error><RequestId>W9WPTXP97BNLX1TFB2VU703TA8TPENLVJ3TBOQ4IS9DMWNJ4SR27</RequestId></ErrorResponse>%
```

My docker compose environment variables:

environment:

- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
- DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
- EDGE_PORT=4566
- SERVICES=sns, sqs
- LS_LOG=trace
  ports:
- '4566:4566'
  volumes:

Has someone experienced this before? How should I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
log from container:

GET localhost:4566/_aws/sqs/messages?QueueUrl=http://queue.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/queue
2023-01-26T17:52:02.045  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS s3.GetObject => 404 (NoSuchBucket); GetObjectRequest({'Bucket': '_aws', 'IfMatch': None, 'IfModifiedSince': None, 'IfNoneMatch': None, 'IfUnmodifiedSince': None, 'Key': 'sqs/messages', 'Range': None, 'ResponseCacheControl': None, 'ResponseContentDisposition': None, 'ResponseContentEncoding': None, 'ResponseContentLanguage': None, 'ResponseContentType': None, 'ResponseExpires': None, 'VersionId': None, 'SSECustomerAlgorithm': None, 'SSECustomerKey': None, 'SSECustomerKeyMD5': None, 'RequestPayer': None, 'PartNumber': None, 'ExpectedBucketOwner': None, 'ChecksumMode': None}, headers={'Host': 'localhost:4566', 'User-Agent': 'curl/7.77.0', 'Accept': '*/*', 'x-localstack-tgt-api': 's3', 'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=000000000000/20160623/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=1234', 'x-localstack-edge': 'http://localhost:4566', 'X-Forwarded-For': '127.0.0.1, localhost:4566', 'Connection': 'close'}); NoSuchBucket(The specified bucket does not exist, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'Content-Length': '258', 'x-amz-request-id': 'Z45RC1D5WHI9WLFRZXV7ARWF3VRVL1V26XCUFDVV946B5XRMA1JN', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'HEAD,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS,PATCH', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'authorization,cache-control,content-length,content-md5,content-type,etag,location,x-amz-acl,x-amz-content-sha256,x-amz-date,x-amz-request-id,x-amz-security-token,x-amz-tagging,x-amz-target,x-amz-user-agent,x-amz-version-id,x-amzn-requestid,x-localstack-target,amz-sdk-invocation-id,amz-sdk-request', 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'etag,x-amz-version-id'})

Comment: I've also been having this problem with S3 in the localstack container. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Hi — Can you pull the latest LocalStack Docker image:

```bash
docker pull localstack/localstack:latest
```

After that, please set your Compose configuration as:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  localstack:
    container_name: "${LOCALSTACK_DOCKER_NAME-localstack_main}"
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:4566:4566"            # LocalStack Gateway
      - "127.0.0.1:4510-4559:4510-4559"  # external services port range
    environment:
      - DEBUG=${DEBUG-}
      - LAMBDA_EXECUTOR=${LAMBDA_EXECUTOR-}
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - LOG_LOG=trace
    volumes:
      - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

The `SERVICES` configuration has been deprecated. After starting the LocalStack container, you can now run the following to verify that the SQS developer endpoints are working:

```bash
$ awslocal sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue
$ awslocal sqs send-message --queue-url http://localhost:4566/00000000000/my-queue --message-body test
$ curl "http://localhost:4566/_aws/sqs/messages?QueueUrl=http://queue.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566/000000000000/my-queue"
```

This should work accurately now!